# C++ Class members recursive pointers? I guess

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to figure out how to do the following. I am trying to implement a few json messages that were implmented in C# in c++ they are not too pivotal to my overall design so if it is impossible. I am cool without but would like to know.

```
\file classA.h

#include"./classB.h"
class a
{
public:
   a();
   virtual ~a();
   json serializeClassA( );
private:
   int _somePrivateInt;
   int _someotherPrivateInt;
   ...
   std::vector<b> _classBVector;
}

\file classB.h

#include "./classA.h"
class b
{
public:
    b();
    virtual ~b();
    json serializeClassB() // pointer to A will serialize as NULL;
private:
    long _somePrivatelong;
    ...
    a * owner;
    
}
```

The C# gives no error when compiling but the above code is a no go with c++ How do I get it to work. Is it a parent child kinda thing or is it a friend class kind of thing.

I thought about making the a * a void * then just casting it when needed but is that the correct answer?

classB.h:36:5: error: ‘a’ does not name a type

Comment: Put some code that you actually expect to compile in the question and instead of "_the above code is a no go with c++_", copy/paste the exact error message into the question.

Comment: classB.h:36:5: error: ‘a’ does not name a type

Comment: You should put the error message in the question, not in comments - but in this case I think the solution is easy. `a` is not a known type in `classB.h`. Try this: Above `class b { ...` write `class a;` (exactly like that). That's a _forward declaration_ and makes it possible to hold pointers to `a` objects within `b` without knowing what `a` actually is.

Comment: Somewhat related: Why does `classB.h` include `classB.h`? That inclusion will recurse endlessly since you don't have header guards. Also why does `classA.h` include `classB.h`?

Comment: You cant have b include a and a include b in c++ because you get into the chicken and egg problem. I am trying to figure out how to overcome the chicken and egg problem using c++.

As I normally program in straight c99 this is a new problem for me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that was a typo sorry class A includes b and b includes a. 

I think the forward declaration might work.

Comment: You need to write @TedLyngmo so that I get a notice. I just happend to have this window open and noticed it.

Ok, fix the typo in the question by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68955385/edit) and also add the header guards you really have in your program (I hope). Yes, circular dependencies are a pain. A forward reference is often the only thing needed to resolve the situation.

Comment: Point is moot now that the questions been closed as a duplicate, but don't edit the question to include the answer. Write an answer.

Comment: Glad it helped and what @user4581301 mentions is also good to remember. If you've struggled with something that made you ask about it here and if you figure the answer out before getting a proper answer from someone else (my comments are not proper answers) - write an answer to your own question. It'll help other people in the future. Perhaps I shouldn't have been so fast on the close button :-)